# Slicing a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to slice a string for the first time.

With this code, if I input, for example 'one two three' it works fine until the last word.
This is the last few lines of the output:

Current word is thr

Sentence is now e

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
    at TestCurr.main(testCurrentWord.java:18)
```

Has anyone any idea why it does that to the last word?

```
class TestCurr
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        String s;
        int i;
        String currentWord;
        int length;
        int spacePos;

        System.out.println("Enter a sentence ");
        s = EasyIn.getString();
        spacePos = s.indexOf(" ");
        length = s.length();

        for (i = length -1; i >= 0;  i--)
            {
                currentWord = s.substring(0,spacePos);
                s = s.substring(spacePos +1);

                System.out.println("Current word is " + currentWord);
                System.out.println("Sentence is now " + s);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider what you are doing _inside_ the loop even after changing `s`.

Comment: I assume this is homework (or the like) and you are trying to learn how to split a string yourself. If not, you should use [the `String.split` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you only get the index of the space once. This causes the program to cut the string every three characters, as the first word is three letters long. You need to update spacePos after each iteration.

Comment: I have spacePos = s.indexOf(" "); inside the loop now and it fixes the problem thanks but I still get the exception

Comment: You have to make sure that it never calls `s.substring(spacePos+1)` if spacePos >= s.length-1.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you call

```
spacePos = s.indexOf(" ");
length = s.length();
```

only once, but these values should change with each iteration of the loop. Furthermore,

```
s.substring(spacePos +1);
```

with

```
spacePos == s.length()-1
```

means you are passing an index beyond the end of the string as the `start` index for `substring()`. Once you fix the first error, this will be your next exception.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is in your usage of your `spacePos` variable.

Outside the loop, you initialize the variable like so:

```
spacePos = s.indexOf(" ");
```

Which in your example string of "one two three", yields 3.

But then inside your loop, you never set the variable again, based on what whatever is left that you haven't processed.

Try re-calculating `spacePos`'s value inside the loop and your problem should go away.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is too error prone.
And you have too many variables.

Try this just as an idea.

```
class TestCurr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = null;

        System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
        s = "   one   two   three   ";
        System.out.println("|" + s + "|");

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while (true){
            while (i<s.length() && s.charAt(i)==' ') i++;
            j = i;
            if (i>=s.length()) break;
            while (i<s.length() && s.charAt(i)!=' ') i++;
            System.out.println("Current word is: [" + s.substring(j, i)+ "]");
            System.out.println("Sentence is now: [" + s.substring(i) + "]");
            if (i>=s.length()) break;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you only get the index once. But I'm curious, why re-invent the wheel?

```
String s = "one two three";
String[] split = s.split(" ");
for (String out : split) {
    System.out.println("Word: " + out);
}
```